# XSD if-else condition

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

I need to make if/else condition in my xsd schema. Specifically pattern node. How I can do it?

```
<s:complexType name="parent">
    <s:sequence>
        <s:element name="elem1" type="s:string"/>
        <s:element name="elem2">
            <s:simpleType>
                <s:restriction base="s:string">
                    <s:pattern value="if (elem1 == 3) //todo 
                                      else //todo"/>
                </s:restriction>
            </s:simpleType>
        </s:element>
   </s:sequence>
</s:complexType name="parent">
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you cannot use `if` within `xs:pattern/@value`.

No, you cannot reference another element within `xs:pattern/@value`.

What you can do:

- **XSD 1.0**: Refactor your XML design and use the core content modeling
  constructs.
- **XSD 1.1**: Conditional Type assignment might help.
- **XSD 1.1**: Assertions might help.

More specific guidance than that is possible only with a more specific question that shows XML that should and should not be valid, that explains `//todo`, etc.